# Remove failing on HashSet despite equals and has code implemented

Tags: java, hashset

Hi I'm writing an integration test for some legacy code and trying to do the following.
Create a deal with a collection of two documents. Persist the deal and documents. Retrieve the deal and remove one of the documents.

However the remove from the HashSet is failing. The equals and hash code methods are implemented on the document class and in the code below I check that the document I'm trying to remove does indeed have the same hash code as one in the collection and does 'equal' it. However removal still fails.

I've even debugged through the HashSet and hash map implementation code and find that internally in the hash map, the method returnEntryForKey appears to be finding the wrong indexFor value?

Am I doing something stupid??

```
    final Entry<K,V> More ...removeEntryForKey(Object key) {
    int hash = (key == null) ? 0 : hash(key.hashCode());
    int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
```

........

```
    @Test 
    public void testDeleteOneOfTwoDocumentsOnlyRemovesOne() 
    { 
            Deal originalDeal = new DealBuilder().withProjectName("test-document-project");

            Document document1 = new DocumentBuilder().withActive(1).withName("Document One").build(); 
            Document document2 = new DocumentBuilder().withActive(1).withName("Document Two").build(); 

            Set<Document> documents = new MyHashSet<Document>(); 
            originalDeal.setDocuments(documents); 
            document1.setDeal(originalDeal); 
            document2.setDeal(originalDeal); 

            originalDeal.getDocuments().add(document1); 
            originalDeal.getDocuments().add(document2); 

            dao.save(originalDeal); 

            Deal savedDeal = dao.findById(originalDeal.getId()); 

            Set<Document> docs = savedDeal.getDocuments(); 

            assertEquals(2l, docs.size()); 

            long docIdToRemove = 0; 

            for (Document document : docs) 
            { 
                    docIdToRemove = document.getId(); 
                    break; 
            } 

            Document docToRemove = docDao.findById(docIdToRemove); 
            System.out.println(docToRemove.hashCode()); 

            for (Document document : docs) 
            { 
                    System.out.println("Hashcode equal? = " + (document.hashCode() == docToRemove.hashCode())); 
                    System.out.println("Objects equal? = " + (document.equals(docToRemove))); 
            } 

            boolean contains = docs.contains(docToRemove); 
            boolean check = docs.remove(docToRemove); 


    } 

    { 

    }
```

}

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. I can think of at least two reasons this could happen...

Comment: I'll post a complete program once at a computer. Can you share what potential issues you are thinking of?

Comment: @Craig Is it possible the properties used to compute the hasCode in Document class change between the time you add a Document to the Set and the time you try to remove it?

Comment: What is MyHashSet? Anything to do with a TreeSet?

Comment: MyHashSet is just a local copy of the HashSet implementation so I could debug through the code.

Comment: There are no changes to the doc. The loop in the code compares the retrieved objects with the document to be deleted for hash code and equals methods and returns ' true, true' for the item I am trying to delete.

Comment: @Craig Yes, but perhaps when the document you are trying to delete was first added to the HashSet it had a different hashCode. It's hard to say without seeing the implementation of hashCode.

Comment: A further note. At the time the docs are added to the set they have no Value in their id property which gets added on persist of the deal object as a cascading persist. The id is part of the hash code but as the item I'm trying to delete is retrieved from the database it also has an id. And the loop confirms the hash codes match.

Comment: One error which often causes problems is if you *overload* equals instead of *overriding* equals. Then your logging will still call the overloaded version - but HashSet will be using the original version in Object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> At the time the docs are added to the set they have no Value in their id property which gets added on persist of the deal object as a cascading persist. The id is part of the hash code but as the item I'm trying to delete is retrieved from the database it also has an id.

That explains everything.

When you enter a doc to the set, the index where it is stored depends on the hashCode at the time it is entered. As you say, it is caculated without the id.

When you try to remove a doc from the set, the index where it is searched for depends on the hashCode of the doc you are trying to remove at the time of the removal attempt.nThis time, as you said, it is calculated with the id, so the hashCode is different.

When those two hashCodes are not equal, the doc to be removed won't be found. It doesn't matter that there's a doc in the set with the same hashCode as the doc you are trying to remove which is also equal to it.

A Further explanation :

When you add a document to the set, the index `i` where it will be stored is computed by :

```
int hash = (key == null) ? 0 : hash(key.hashCode());
int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
```

where `key.hashCode()` is the document's hashCode.

When you try to remove a document from the set, the index `i` where that doc will be search is computed the same way. If the document's hashCode has changed in the meantime, the computed `i` will probably be different, and the document won't be searched where it's actaully located, so it won't be found.

In order to solve your problem, you should add the documents to the set only after the id property is set. If that's not possible, you can create a new HashSet adding all the documents from the old Set to it. This will place the documents in the HashSet based on the updated value of their hashCode.